# Android WebView - onCreateWindow of Message.getData().getString("url") return null with <a> Tag created by createElement()

Tags: javascript, android, webview, createelement, atag

I am meeting an issue with onCreateWindow of Android WebView
This is my Codes :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

      final WebView newWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());

      Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
      view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);

      final String url = href.getData().getString("url");
      final String title = href.getData().getString("title");
      /*
      Run Some Codes for sending data (url + title string)
      */
      return false;
   }
```

Basically, i want to listen for urls which will open in new window (with target="_blank").
These above codes work perfect with a tags in the dom, but with the tags those were created by createElement("a") javascript code & open by run aTag.click() then the url variable always return null.
Perhaps because createElement itself did not insert the tag to html dom, so requestFocusNodeHref() wasn't found any a tag (it does not really exists in the WebView object).

Whether there are any solution to capture links with this type of a tag ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: facing similar problem, when tags appears inside <span> , onCreateWindow gives URL = null, so I am not able to launch the link in new window

Comment: Did you try shouldoverrideurlloading in WebViewClient? 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Answer (score 1):

Try using shouldoverideurlloading like this, so just add this method:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        // Handle URL loading as per your requirements
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        String title = request.getData().toString(); // adjuste this
        /*
        Run Some Codes for sending data (url + title string)
        */

        return true; // Return true to indicate that you're handling the URL loading
    }
```